# Getting values from Object.values() with omitting null and empty

Tags: javascript

When I extract the value, I would like to remove the `null`, `undefined` or empty from the values. What would be the correct way to do that?

My code:

```js
const address = {
  stateProvince: null,
  streetAddress: '15900 Valley View Ct',
  streetAddress2: 'TF2',
  streetAddress3: '2',
  city: 'Sylmar',
  zipCode: '91342',
  countryCd: 140,
  stateCd: 75,
};

const values = Object.values(address);
console.log(values) // [null, '15900 Valley View Ct', 'TF2', '2', 'Sylmar', '91342', 140, 75];
```

I am getting `null` in the result.

Comment: You can use the `filter` function on your array of values

Comment: Object.values(address).filter(.... and filter out non nulls

Comment: `Object.values().filter((v) => v!= undefined)`. Do not use `!!value` as you will need `0`, `false` and `''`